# remove footer for lightning data table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datatable

I want to remove the standard buttons "Cancel" and "Save" in a lightning dataTable when a record is edited. I want to retrieve the values for a Wrapper Class through the onchange event when the record is edited, but I don't want to visualize the default buttons of the component[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Please post your code, so that folks here can help

Comment: I dont recal those buttons being part of the datatable, they must have been added there, you will have to post your code for further assistance

Answer (score 3):

You can use
`<lightning:datatable suppressBottomBar="true" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

Using inline edit will automatically make those appear since it evaluates the `draftvalues` attribute. The yellow also appears when you have any changes.

Assuming you solve for that, you can inspect the element generated and just use a CSS override to `visibility: hidden`. Of course, subject to break if they change their container or css classes for you to target.

There's not really an onchange event for the cell from what I can recall. You might get away with putting a change handler on the `v.draftvalues` attribute but I'm not sure that will work for sure?

Comment: Thanks @tsalb, I decided used that buttons. As you mentioned draftvalues can be useful, so I will use it, as the buttons too.